# Create Oracle function/macro with an undeterminate number of arguments

Tags: oracle, function, macros

Is it possible to create an Oracle PL/SQL function or macro that would help me generate some code?

for example

```
sumnull(a,b)
```

would return

```
coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) +
        (case when coalesce(a, b) is not null then 0 else null end)
```

and

```
sumnull(a,b,c)
```

would return

```
coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) + coalesce(c, 0) +
        (case when coalesce(a, b, c ) is not null then 0 else null end)
```

but sumnull could take more than 3 arguments as well (a,b,c,d,e.....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a variable number of arguments in the C `varargs` sense (for example). You can overload a function so you have a version that takes 2, another that takes 3, etc., which would be a pain to maintain; or have a long list of values with them all defaulting to zero:

```
create or replace function sumnull (p_1 number default null, p_2 number default null,
  p_3 number default null, p_4 number default null /*, etc. */)
return number as
begin
  return coalesce(p_1, 0) + coalesce(p_2, 0)
    + coalesce(p_3, 0) + coalesce(p_4, 0) /* + etc. */;
end;
/

select sumnull() from dual;

 SUMNULL()
----------
         0 

select sumnull(null) from dual;

SUMNULL(NULL)
-------------
            0 

select sumnull(1,null,7,9) from dual;

SUMNULL(1,NULL,7,9)
-------------------
                 17
```

But you still have to set an upper limit at some point, and it'll error if you try to send too many argument, with PLS-00306. And it gets a bit tedious and potentially error-prone repeating the clauses.

Another option is to pass a collection of values, something like:

```
create or replace function sumnull (p_values sys.odcinumberlist)
return number as
  l_total number := 0;
begin
  if p_values is null or p_values.count = 0 then
    return l_total;
  end if;

  for i in 1..p_values.count loop
    l_total := l_total + coalesce(p_values(i), 0);
  end loop;

  return l_total;
end;
/
```

Then you can call it like:

```
select sumnull(null) from dual;

SUMNULL(NULL)
-------------
            0 

select sumnull(sys.odcinumberlist()) from dual;

SUMNULL(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST())
-----------------------------
                            0 

select sumnull(sys.odcinumberlist(1,null,7,9)) from dual;

SUMNULL(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,NULL,7,9))
---------------------------------------
                                     17
```

You can pass in column names as part of a larger query too; using a CTE for dummy data here:

```
with t as (select 1 as a, null as b, 7 as c, 9 as d from dual)
select sumnull(sys.odcinumberlist(a, b, c, d)) from t;

SUMNULL(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(A,B,C,D))
------------------------------------
                                  17
```

You can define your own collection type at SQL level of course, the [built-in `sys.odcinumberlist`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI4964) is just convenient.

Comment: Thanks! So out of curiosity, how does Coalesce() do to have an undeterminate number of arguments?

Comment: And instead of numbers, can I have Column names as arguments?

Comment: Mmm, good question; I imagine it's implemented at a lower level, in C or whatever as part of the core DB code, not in PL/SQL. Although that raises the possibility of using a Java function I suppose. I think coalesce is still limited to 1000 arguments, which is the normal limit on a list of values.

Comment: @Stephane - yes, I've added an example of that to the answer.